# Unable to locate the elements in the "inline" form

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am trying to complete a project for a class, however, I am unable to locate the elements as shown in the design spec of the project. Everything in the ".right" class should be horizontal to the ".left" class elements. Can you please help me out? How to write the CSS rules so that the output looks like in the picture?

```
  <div class="left">
    <img src="C:\colmar\information-main.jpg"/>
    <div class="text">
      <h2>It doesn`t hurt to keep practicing</h2>
      <p>"Curabitur vitae libero in ipsum portitor consequat. Aliquam et commodo lectus, <br/> nec consequat neque. Sed non accumsan uma. Phasellus sed consequat ex. Etiam <br/> eget magna laoreet, eficitur dolor consequat, tristique ligula."</p>
      <span>Emanuel, Sr Strategist at Hiring.com</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="orientation">
      <img src="C:\colmar\information-orientation.jpg"/>
      <h4>Orientation date</h4>
      <p>Tue 10/11 and Wed 10/12: 8am - 3pm</p>
      <a href="read"Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="campus">
      <img src="C:\colmar\information-campus.jpg"/>
      <h4>Our campus</h4>
      <p>Find which campus is close by you</p>
      <a href="read_more"Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="lecture">
      <img src="C:\colmar\information-guest-lecture.jpg"/>
      <h4>Our guest lecture</h4>
      <p>Join a keynote with Oliver Sack <br/>about music in medical treatment</p>
      <a href="more">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: What "picture"?

Comment: What does _"can't locate the elements"_ mean? What does your current result look like? Please turn your code into a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers). What exactly is your issue? _"Can you please help me out?"_ is an [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. Please check out [ask] as well as [these details on homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), then edit your question accordingly. Cheers.

Comment: There is an image that shows how the webpage should look when the project is done. There is a link to the image at the bottom of the question box. I could do the elements on the left side, however, I am having trouble with the ".right" class elements.

Comment: Also, as a general hint in the right direction, read about [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes), margins and paddings. Or, if your assignment requires you to use floats, read about those. Plus, why did you take a screenshot of an image and uploaded that instead of uploading the actual image itself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes according to @domsson you have to put some efforts for CSS and div alignment.Apart of this let me help you for some start.check the following code for the base help.

> code style:

```
.container
{
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: block !important;
    position: relative;
}
.left
{
  width: calc(48px + 60%);
  float:left;
}
.right
{
  width: calc(40% - 48px);
  float:left;
}
h2
{
    margin: 32px 0px 32px 0px;  
}
```

> for html :

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
    <img src="C:\colmar\information-main.jpg"/>
    <div class="text">
      <h2>It doesn`t hurt to keep practicing</h2>
      <p>"Curabitur vitae libero in ipsum portitor consequat. Aliquam et commodo lectus, <br/> nec consequat neque. Sed non accumsan uma. Phasellus sed consequat ex. Etiam <br/> eget magna laoreet, eficitur dolor consequat, tristique ligula."</p>
      <span>Emanuel, Sr Strategist at Hiring.com</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="orientation">
      <img src="C:\colmar\information-orientation.jpg"/>
      <h4>Orientation date</h4>
      <p>Tue 10/11 and Wed 10/12: 8am - 3pm</p>
      <a href="read"Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="campus">
      <img src="C:\colmar\information-campus.jpg"/>
      <h4>Our campus</h4>
      <p>Find which campus is close by you</p>
      <a href="read_more"Read more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="lecture">
      <img src="C:\colmar\information-guest-lecture.jpg"/>
      <h4>Our guest lecture</h4>
      <p>Join a keynote with Oliver Sack <br/>about music in medical treatment</p>
      <a href="more">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `!important` is something that should only be used if absolutely necessary, I don't think it should be used here (OP might not look into it further and simply use it in other places). Also, the markup wouldn't even validate. Check, for example, `<a href="read_more"Read more</a>`. The use of `<br/>` to ensure line breaks where they naturally appear in the layout template is also questionable. In other words: if you want to kick-start OP with some pointers, I'd suggest to also include these basic and important things.